# Tikz-drawing Brownian motion on the unit circle $S^{1}$

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw Brownian motion on the unit circle `$S^{1}$` `$({Z \in \mathbb{C} : |Z|=1})$` using the package TikZ. Here is the picture that I am trying to get:

[image]

I have just a simple example to circle :

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \draw (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### With PSTricks (version 1)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\everypsbox{\scriptsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle[linecolor=blue]{1}
    \qdisk(0,0){2pt}
    \qdisk(1;30){2pt}
    \psline(1;30)
    \uput{4pt}[-100](1;30){$z$}
    \rput{30}(1;30){%
        \psline[linecolor=red]{<->}(0,1)(0,0)(1,0)%
        \psarc[arcsep=\pslinewidth](0,0){6pt}{0}{90}%
        \uput{2pt}[30]{*0}(0,1){$i_z$}%
        \uput{2pt}[-45]{*0}(1,0){$z$}%
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With PSTricks (version 2)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridcolor=orange}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pnode(0,0){O}
    \pnode(1;30){P}
    \pnode([nodesep=-1]{O}P){X}
    \pnode([offset=-1]{O}P){Y}
    \pscircle[linecolor=blue](O){1}
    \qdisk(O){2pt}
    \qdisk(P){2pt}
    \psline(P)
    \psline[linecolor=red]{<->}(X)(P)(Y)
    \psarc[arcsep=\pslinewidth,origin={P}](P){6pt}{(X)}{(Y)}
    \psset{labelsep=3pt}
    \uput[-20](P){$z$}
    \uput[20](Y){$i_z$}
    \uput[0](X){$z$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Without PSTricks

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=stealth]
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle (1);
    \fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
    \fill (30:1) circle (1pt);
    \draw (0,0) -- (30:1);
    \node[anchor=150] at (30:1) {$z$};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(30:1)},rotate=30]
    \node[anchor=west] at (0,1) {$i_z$};
    \node[anchor=north] at (1,0) {$z$};
    \draw[red,<->] (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw (0:6pt) arc (0:90:6pt);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi Thanks Mr Mozartstrabe so much now it's  work for me when i Compile it with xelatex or latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf  in latex but please if you could to make it wit Tikz

Comment: Thanks so much Mr mozarstrabe it's work but i prefer in Tikz Thanks again

Comment: Thanks so much just on question how can i make it big in pdf because it plots small in my document

Comment: Thanks so much for ur time and ur help Please accept,Mr Mozarstrabe , the assurances of my highest consideration

Comment: @Educ: Mozartstrasse not Mozartstrabe. :-)

Comment: sorry Mr Mozartstrasse